# How can I find out if a specific GeoLocation is on a motorway, in a urban area or outside a urban area (using OSM Nominatim)?

Tags: openstreetmap, geolocation, nominatim

I have a list of geo-locations (latitude, longitude) as a track of a vehicle driving around the country. I need to find out how many kilometers did the vehicle drove on the motorway, inside urban areas or outside urban areas.

Most probably I will not find such a function that takes a set of coordinates (could be thousands in a single call) and return the distances per type of area.

So probably I will need to find out, location by location, if is on a motorway, in a urban area or outside urban area.

By urban we can think of any settlement with inhabitants (city, village, town, suburb, neighbourhood). I can complete the list in time with different places.

Which methods I should use?

We are using OpenStreetMap Nominatim service installed locally.

Comment: You need to look at intersection, it's very efficient for line strings and polygons and should solve your problem quickly and easily

Comment: thanks for the quick response. can you please share more details about how to use intersections to identify where the location is? what if a road passes a settlement without any intersections (small villages)? Or what about the motorway that could have for kilometers no intersection?

Comment: What data do you have of where there are motorways, urban arean, not urban etc.?